# A is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Show that there exist $2 \times 2$ matrices with certain rank requirements.

Tags: matrix-rank

> A is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Show that there exist $2 \times 2$ matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that $\textrm{rank}(A+B_1)=1$ and $\textrm{rank}(A+B_2)=2$.

I can write examples of $B_1$ and $B_2$, but could anyone give me a more thorough answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Let $C$ be your favorite rank 1 $2\times2$ matrix, let $D$ be your favorite rank 2 $2\times2$ matrix, let $B_1=C-A$, let $B_2=D-A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had the same thought - if you want to post yours as an answer I will gladly delete mine.

Comment: @Zubin, please don't delete your answer on account of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Find *any* $2$ by $2$ matrix with rank $1$, call it $C$. Find *any* $2$ by $2$ matrix with rank $2$, call it $D$.

Now, for *any* $A$, you can let $B_1=C-A$ and $B_2=D-A$. These differences exist because the set of $2$ by $2$ matrices is [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) under subtraction, so $B_1$ and $B_2$ exist.